# JQuery can't get value of dynamically added fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden div with a simple form:

```
<div id="mb_clookup" style="display: none;">
    <strong><font color="#0066CC">Search for existing customers</font></strong><br /><br />
    <font color="#FFF">
        Postcode: <input type="text" name="cl_zipcode" id="cl_zipcode" />
        <span id="cl_search">Search</span>
    </font>
</div>
```

This is displayed when the user clicks a button on the page. The user puts in the ZIP code, click on search and a JSON query is called. I have managed to make the Search button work with .live() but I cannot get the value of the input field. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).on( "click", "#cl_search", function() {
        var pc = $('#cl_zipcode').val();

        if(pc === '') {
           alert('Please type in a post code first.');
        }
        else {
            // JSON
        }
    });
});
```

Th pc variable comes up empty. I tried:`$(this).find('#cl_zipcode').val()` this comes up with undefined.
Please advise.

Comment: Perhaps you can share the entire form in a Fiddle

Comment: why you have === equal compare? also did you put alert on pc variable. it should work `$("#cl_zipcode")` as your form is hidden not dynamically added.

Comment: @ShikharBhardwaj it will work because your example doesn't have that form hidden like his. give him example with hidden form.

Comment: As your original code actually works, perhaps you can share the rest of the code. You mention dynamically adding fields, so that code is *very* important to see here.

Comment: I tried your code in codepen and it works. Now your code has a plethora of problems like the use of dead tags like font, using a span as a button, not using the label tag to actually label the input, etc. but still the value gets read correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following

```
var pc= $("#mb_clookup").find('#cl_zipcode').val();
```

or

```
var pc= $("#mb_clookup :input").val();
```

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5tg24om/)

Answer (score 1):

With regard to `$(this).find('#cl_zipcode').val()` the input elements is *beside* the clicked span, so your find will search from the span on down (and it contains nothing aside from the text).

You need to move up the DOM first before you find it.

```
$(this).parent().find('#cl_zipcode').val()
```

Please note that as IDs are unique, so your original code is actually fine (so long as you only have one of these added): http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/djqfharu/

If you load more than one of these (you mention dynamic adding of fields) you will need to switch to classes to identify the elements.

e.g

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).on( "click", ".cl_search", function() {
        var pc = $(this).parent().find('.cl_zipcode').val()
        if(pc === '') {
           alert('Please type in a post code first.');
        }
        else {
            // JSON
        }
    });
});
```

This is because browser keeps a fast-lookup dictionary, of IDs vs DOM elements, so only a single entry is retained per ID. The upshot of that is that jQuery can only ever find the first matching element for a search of a duplicated ID. The solution there is to switch to using classes and class-based searched.

**I strongly suggest you post the rest of your code as the part shown is not the problem *in isolation*.**

Answer (score 0):

i thing your html code wrong. Becouse  tag not in use  tag
 tag not support HTML5..

change this

```
<div id="mb_clookup" style="display:block;">
    <strong><font color="#0066CC">Search for existing customers</font></strong><br /><br />
    <span style="color="#FFF">
        Postcode: <input type="text" name="cl_zipcode" id="cl_zipcode" />
        <span id="cl_search">Search</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

good luck

Comment: ops never said he is using html 5 :(

Comment: The HTML works fine. Browsers are very tolerant of mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine i checked it in `jsfiddle` by removing display none attribute. You can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ysvsqobk/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="mb_clookup">
    <strong><font color="#0066CC">Search for existing customers</font></strong><br /><br />
    <font color="#FFF">
    Postcode: <input type="text" name="cl_zipcode" id="cl_zipcode" />
        <button id="cl_search">Search</button>
    </font>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).on( "click", "#cl_search", function() {
        var pc = $('#cl_zipcode').val();
        if(pc === '') {
           alert('Please type in a post code first.');
        }
        else {
            alert(pc);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes you, and about 3 others, noticed it works *in isolation*, but that is not the problem :)